# Mapper Class and Reducer Class in MapReduce Design pattern

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to MapReduce and I have some doubt on this code on the Mapper class and Reducer Class design

I am familiar with Map Side Joining in MapReduce and I learned this:

```
public static class CustsMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

Here, in the above code snippet I learned that we extends our class to `Mapper` class and as the `Object` is a key and `Text` is a value so map method take this key-value as an input with the `context` object helps here like this as an output `context.write(new Text(), new Text())` as per the design of the logic body of the code.

My two questions are:

1. Why we have extended our class to `MapReduceBase`(what it does?) and why we have implemented our class to `Mapper`(I knew it's a class but in
   the web somewhere its showing as an interface so if I extends it to
   `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>`
   class what is the problem?
2. In the `map` function what does `OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter` ?? I didn't know it? I knew that `Context
   context` should be here but what is `OutputCollector` and `Reporter`
   here?

**I was doing this program given below:**

**Input:**

```
1979   23   23   2   43   24   25   26   26   26   26   25   26  25 
1980   26   27   28  28   28   30   31   31   31   30   30   30  29 
1981   31   32   32  32   33   34   35   36   36   34   34   34  34 
1984   39   38   39  39   39   41   42   43   40   39   38   38  40 
1985   38   39   39  39   39   41   41   41   00   40   39   39  45
```

**Code:**

```
package hadoop; 

import java.util.*; 

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.IOException; 

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*; 

public class ProcessUnits 
{ 
   //Mapper class 
   public static class E_EMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable ,Text,Text,IntWritable>       
   {       
      //Map function 
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
      { 
         String line = value.toString(); 
         String lasttoken = null; 
         StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,"\t"); 
         String year = s.nextToken(); 

         while(s.hasMoreTokens())
            {
               lasttoken=s.nextToken();
            } 

         int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken); 
         output.collect(new Text(year), new IntWritable(avgprice)); 
      } 
   } 


   //Reducer class 
   public static class E_EReduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer< Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> 
   {     
      //Reduce function 
      public void reduce( Text key, Iterator <IntWritable> values, 
         OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
         { 
            int maxavg=30; 
            int val=Integer.MIN_VALUE; 

            while (values.hasNext()) 
            { 
               if((val=values.next().get())>maxavg) 
               { 
                  output.collect(key, new IntWritable(val)); 
               } 
            } 

         } 
   }  


   //Main function 
   public static void main(String args[])throws Exception 
   { 
      JobConf conf = new JobConf(ProcessUnits.class); 

      conf.setJobName("max_eletricityunits"); 
      conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 
      conf.setMapperClass(E_EMapper.class); 
      conf.setCombinerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setReducerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class); 
      conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class); 

      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0])); 
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1])); 

      JobClient.runJob(conf); 
   } 
}
```

**Output:**

```
1981    34 
1984    40 
1985    45
```

Comment: `mapred.*;` are the old API classes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269922/hadoop-mapred-vs-hadoop-mapreduce

Comment: OutputCollector is the old way of Context.write

Comment: Dear @cricket_007 Ok, but what does OutputCollector and Reporter? Is it work similar like `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*`?  is it just the old API? Right?

Comment: The mapreduce package uses Mapper and Reducer as full classes, not interfaces

Comment: Dear @cricket_007 Yes, you meant that the interfaces at the old API(mapred.*) and the classes has come at the new(mapreduce.*).

Comment: Feel free to read the JavaDoc, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why we have extended our class to MapReduceBase(what it does?) and why we have implemented our class to Mapper

Because that's old code written with the mapred API before  Hadoop 2.x was around.

> I knew that Context context should be here but what is OutputCollector and Reporter here

It's the previous version of the Context object.

[Hadoop: How does OutputCollector work during MapReduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996963/hadoop-how-does-outputcollector-work-during-mapreduce)
[How outputcollector works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763478/how-outputcollector-works)